# Calculation roots of determinant of matrix polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in {\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}}$ and ${t_0} \in \left( {0,1} \right)$ if fix.

Suppose

- $N = \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{C}:\det (({A_2} + {t_0}{B_2}){x^2} + ({A_1} + {t_0}{B_1})x + ({A_0} + {t_0}{B_0})) = 0} \right\}$
- $M = \left\{ {x \in \mathbb{C}:\det (({A_2} + {B_2}){x^2} + ({A_1} + {B_1})x + ({A_0} + {B_0})) = 0} \right\}$

Why is $N \subseteq M$ true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\det C$ is a polynomial in the elements of $C$, and therefore is continuous in them.

Comment: What is $detC$?

Comment: The determinant of a matrix $C$. I am saying that for any matrix, the determinant is a continuous function of its elements. And you should also note that for the matrix you are taking the determinant of in $N$, the elements of it are all continuous functions of $t_0$.